# python replace special characters except dashes and periods

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace every special character but leave dashes and periods. I have `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', corpus`, which replaces everything. How do I modify it to leave periods and dashes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add periods and dashes to the negated character class.

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z.-]+', ' ', corpus)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example string.

```
string = 'He$llo i a@m-Not 12.34 $'

re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 .-]',r'',string)
```

Output: `'Hello i am-Not 12.34'`